# How to work request.render in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, rendering

I am using `GET` and `POST` methods for getting data from the server and getting response using `request.send(object);`.

However my requirements changed, I need to use `request.render('pageName',object);` but the render method refreshes my  page but I only want to refresh a particular `<div>` section. I read on this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs but I am not able to refresh only particular section without refreshing the entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redraw only a part of the page then you probably need some kind of client-side rendering for your templates. You fetch the data from the server using `GET` just like you mentioned and then do the actual drawing of the page on the client instead of sending HTML with `request.render`.

Comment: Hello Rick can i do using 'request.render('pageName',object);' or not ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. What `request.render` does is basically render the entire template and send the HTML back to the client. Of course you could split your templates into smaller parts and then request those parts individually and insert them into the DOM using jQuery but that's not really a good solution.